# Angular 2 - Router instance for lazy loaded components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am able to get the router instance in root module component with the following snippet

```
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(public router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
        if ((evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
            console.log(evt.url);
        }
    });
}
```

But the same code is not working in Lazy loaded component. Here is the routing for lazy loading module

```
{
    path: 'registration',
    loadChildren: '../registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'
}
```

when I am calling any path say `/registration/startup-registration` above mention code is not working. 
Please suggest the way to achieve the same.

Comment: Lazy loaded routes have different events. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events). Specifically, see `RouteConfigLoadStart` and `RouteConfigLoadEnd`.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware about lazy loaded routes. Some one marked this question wrong.